# Writing Hibernate Request

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I want to write a Hibenate Request, my Sql Request is like this :

> Select city , count(*) from user group by city;

Thanks !

Comment: SO is not a code generator. Show us what have you tried. Btw, you have numerous examples how to execute such a query in Hibernate.

Comment: You can request it through hibernate also.search `sql with hibernate`

Answer (score 2):

Use the code snippet

```
session.createSQLQuery("Select city , count(*) from user group by city");
```

The Hibernate can be used to write raw SQL code in the query.

EDIT:

As suggested hibernate also have it's own query language HQL which allows to create `Query`. And it uses more user friendly interface to query objects instead of tables. In your case the query would rewrite like

```
session.createQuery("Select user.city, count(*) from User as user group by user.city");
```

not a big difference but the object User is used instead of table, and its attributes.

With the criteria API the same could be achieved using projections in

```
session.createCriteria(User.class)
  .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.rowCount())
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("city"))
  );
```

Comment: +1 it would be better to suggest criteria and hql possibilities also.